# Effective access time and Average access time

Tags: caching, memory-management, cpu-architecture

What is the difference between Effective access time and  Average access time.(Please tell from "Operating system" and "computer organization" point of view)

Comment: What textbook are you using?  I don't think "effective access time" is widely-used terminology with a standard meaning.  If I had to guess, maybe it's the latency for a specific access, as opposed to an average over multiple accesses.

Comment: Effective and Average are quite confusing

Answer (score -1):

More often than not, we ignore weights while finding arithmetic means. Effective access time and average access time have a very subtle difference between them. 
Say, I have a memory with access time 100. I also have a cache with hit rate of 90% and access time of 10. Now, we need to find the 'average' access time for the memory.

We know that 90% of  time, the access time will be 10 and for the remaining 10% of the time, the access time will be 100***. So, effectively, the access time for the system will be (90/100)*10+(10/100)*100. This is referred to as effective access time. In statistical term, weighted average.

Average access time simply means the two weights are equal. Or in other words, the two events are equally probable and therefore will contribute equally to the final mean of the system. In that case, the average will be 
(50/100)*10+(50/100)*100= (1/2)(100+10) which is the average which we have been using ever since(add the two and divide it by 2).

*** The access time will be more than 100 since we need to account for the cache search time as well and also the bus latency. The example is just cooked up and does not represent accurate modeling of the access time.